# "Use of unassigned local variable 'result'"

Tags: visual-studio

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(GetMax(2, 10, 40));
    }
    static int GetMax(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        int result;
        if (num1 >= num2 && num1 >= num3)
        {
            result = num1;
        }
        else if (num2 >= num1 && num2 >= num3)
        {
            result = num2;
        }
        else if (num3 >= num1 && num3 >= num2)
        {
            result = num3;
        };
        return result;
    }
```

"result" is underlined. im trying to return the maximum number to the main method but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is just that you need to initialize 'result' with something first. At the beginning of your GetMax function, instead of:

```
int result;
```

try:

```
int result = 0;
```

By initializing the value as something, you should be good.

Another option would be to pass an array to GetMax instead of individual numbers. Then use a for loop to go through the array and assign the biggest one to 'result'. This method would allow you to compare arrays of any length of numbers, not just 3:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] numbers = {2, 10, 40};
    Console.WriteLine(GetMax(numbers));
}

static int GetMax(int[] nums)
{
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i ++)
  if (nums[i] > result){
    result = nums[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Hope one of these options works for you!